# Number theory Discrete Math

Tags: number-theory

prove gcd(n,n+2) = 1 or 2. What possible values can gcd(n,n+3) have what about gcd(n,n+4). What about gcd(n.n+k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $d$ divides $m$ and $d$ divides $n$, then $d$ divides $n - m$.

Recall that the gcd of $m$ and $n$ is the largest positive integer that divides both $m$ and $n$, and that $d$ divides $n$ if $dk = n$ for some integer $k$ (by definition).

Comment: little more help ? is that like saying a = n mod m then m|a-n ?? still lost

Comment: If $d$ divides $m$ and $d$ divides $n$, that is the same as saying that $m\equiv n\equiv 0\pmod{d}$.

Comment: You'll want to use the definition of divisibility to prove the hint: if $d$ divides $m$ and $n$, then we have (by definition) $m = dk$, $n = dk'$ for some integers $k$ and $k'$. What can you say about $m - n$ now?

It might also help to look at an example or two to understand the hint. $2$ divides both $4$ and $6$, and $6 - 4 = 2$ is also divisible by $2$. $10$ divides both $100$ and $250$, and it also divides $250 - 100 = 150$.

Comment: Let q > 2 be an integer. If q divides n and n + 2, then q divides n + 2 - n = 2. But since q > 2, this is a contradiction that shows no q > 2 is the gcd of n and n + 2. It follows that, for every positive integer n, gcd(n, n + 2) is 1 or 2.

Comment: now about gcd(n,n+k) would it be values < k?

Comment: would it be 1 or k for the last one??

Comment: For your first part, it's true that no $q > 2$ can be the gcd of $n$ and $n + 2$. I wouldn't use contradiction though: you can be very direct here. If $q = \gcd(n, n + 2)$, then $q$ divides $n$ and $n + 2$. Hence, by the hint, $q$ divides $2$. But what divides $2$? For $n$ and $n + k$, try this example: the gcd of $2$ and $6$ is $2$, but $6 - 2 = 4$. So here $k = 4$, but the gcd is $\gcd(2, 2 + 4) = 2$ (not $1$ and not $4$). You should try to understand how the hint applies in this situation.

Comment: I get it now, gcd(n,n+k) will be factors of k